# VScode autosuggest - way to tell what tags abbreviation means?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, tags, emmet

[Atom text editor showing 'td' is 'table data'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cf6kT.png)
[vscode emmet abbreviation for p element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4uov.png)

Is there a way in VScode's autosuggest to have it explain what each element is, like how it does in Atom? For example, showing 'p' is 'Paragraph' when the letter 'p' is typed. I just want a way to have it show what the abbreviation means in the autosuggest (autosuggest is working aside from that). Is there an extension or something I need to enable?

Answer (score 0):

just install extensions in vsCode
Ex:1. HTML CSS support
2.IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML
3.HTML boilerplate ...etc..

ex:if you are working on REACT, you need to install React extensions,